# Delay function execution if it has been called recently

Tags: javascript

as implied in the title, I have a function that is going to be called multiple times quickly. However it must not execute less than 1 second after it has been called lastly.

I've made the following code but it seems messy to me and I feel like there must be something better...

```
let available = true
let requested = 0

function notTwiceASecond() {
    if (available) {
        console.log('Executed')
        // ...
        available = false
        setTimeout(() => {
            available = true
            if (requested) {
                notTwiceASecond()
                requested--
            }
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        console.log('Still on cooldown')
        requested++
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    notTwiceASecond()
}
```

Although it works just fine, after doing some research I think the way to go is using async/await but I'm fairly inexperienced with JS and don't know how to implement it properly.

Comment: This is often referred to as `debouncing`. That might help your searching.

Comment: Debounce is a term I have seen used to describe this functionality. Might be something there to help you.

Comment: You did well, async/await would not help your code a whole lot, it's absolutely fine!

Comment: This is actually the opposite of how debouncing usually works. With debouncing, you wait until you stop calling the function for some time, then execute the last one. A good example is when you're doing auto-fill -- you wait until the user stops typing before filling in.

Comment: Whether `async`/`await` is the right way to go depends on what you're trying to achieve in the bigger picture. From the question itself I cannot say whether it would be a good idea to go that way or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The question

Like a debouncer, you *don't* want to *immediately execute* on each call. But unlike a debouncer, you want to have each call *queued for future execution.*

Like a scheduler, you want to specify *when* to call the queued calls. More specifically, you want to execute calls with a *fixed delay* inbetween each call.

This means we can take inspiration from different ideas:

- From debouncers: How to not execute on every call.
- From queues: How to organize calls (first-in-first-out (FIFO) is what we want).
- From schedulers: How to manage calls.

### With `async`/`await`

Using `async`/`await` is a great idea! Note that in JS there is no way to `sleep()` natively because of its original synchronous design. We could either implement `sleep()` synchronously by [spinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) (**highly discouraged** because it will make your site unresponsive) or asynchronously with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Example of how a `sleep()` function can be implemented asynchronously:

```js
function sleep(milli) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milli));
}
```

Now, to refactor your code to use `async`/`await`, we mostly only need to inline the `setTimeout()` function. Simply put, until the `setTimeout()` call we can do as usual, then `sleep()` for the specified time (1000 milliseconds), and then inline the callback:

```js
function sleep(milli) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milli));
}
let available = true;
let requested = 0;
async function notTwiceASecond() {
  if (available) {
    available = false;
    
    console.log("Executed");
    // ...
    
    await sleep(1000);
    available = true;
    if (requested) {
      --requested;
      notTwiceASecond();
    }
  } else {
    ++requested;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  console.log("called");
  notTwiceASecond();
}
```

Since we want to `await` the `sleep()` call, we have to declare `notTwiceASecond()` as `async`.

One **important** thing I'd like to mention is that I moved `available = false` to the top of the if-block. I did this for several reasons:

- Semantically, we have just started working on the call, so we should be unavailable from the beginning.
- Programmatically because if we were to call `notTwiceASecond()` from within the left-out code (`// ...`), your function would behave differently from how it should. This bug also exists in your original code.

Refactoring your code like this will change its behaviour with other `setTimeout()` calls and Promises, because of [how the event loop works](https://web.archive.org/web/20211021172912/https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-promises-settimeout/).
Here a short example of the differences:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(3);
}, 0);

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  console.log(2);
});

console.log(1);
```

### Initial answer

Simple debouncing can be done with a delayed action. In JS we can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) for the delayed action. Do note that a regular debounce will act as if only the last call has been made, like this:

```js
let timeoutId = undefined;
function debounce(callback) {
  // Clear previous delayed action, if existent
  if (timeoutId !== undefined) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = undefined;
  }
  
  // Start new delayed action for latest call
  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
    timeoutId = undefined; // Clear timeout
  }, 1000);
}

const callback = () => console.log("debounced!");
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  debounce(callback);
}
```

But we don't want to dismiss past calls. Actually, we want to act on the first call, and enqueue future calls!

```js
const queue = [];
let timeoutId = undefined;
function weirdDebounce(callback) {
  if (timeoutId === undefined) {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
      timeoutId = undefined;
      console.log("[DEBUG] Queue-length:", queue.length);
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    queue.push(callback);
  }
}

const callback = () => console.log('"debounced"!');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  weirdDebounce(callback);
}
```

Now that "act on first call" and "enqueue further calls" is in place, we only need to actually execute the enqueued calls after some delay.

```js
const queue = [];
let timeoutId = undefined;
function weirdDebounceAndSchedule(callback) {
  function pauseThenContinue() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      timeoutId = undefined;
      doNext();
    }, 1000);
  }
  function doNext() {
    // Only do next if available and no delayed action is in progress
    if (queue.length && timeoutId === undefined) {
      const nextCallback = queue.shift();
      nextCallback();
      pauseThenContinue();
    }
  }
  
  queue.push(callback);
  doNext();
}

const callback = () => console.log("now scheduled!");
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  weirdDebounceAndSchedule(callback);
}
```

#### Better "initial answer"

Maybe you want to be able to have different such "debounced" functions, and maybe you want to have them run independently of each other. If so, you might want to use the following implementation.

From the previous explanations, I hope it is understandable how this one work, though the previous explanations are actually derived from this code:

```js
/**
 * Create a scheduler for calling callbacks with a fixed delay inbetween each call.
 * 
 * @param milli the inbetween-delay in milliseconds
 * @returns a function to add callbacks to the queue
 */
function withPause(milli) {
  const queue = [];
  let timeoutId = undefined;
  function pauseThenContinue() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(
      function() {
        timeoutId = undefined;
        doNext();
      },
      milli
    );
  }
  function doNext() {
    if (queue.length && timeoutId === undefined) {
      queue.shift()();
      pauseThenContinue();
    }
  }
  return function(callback) {
    queue.push(callback);
    doNext();
  };
}

// Can be used like this:
const doTask = withPause(1000);
for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  doTask(() => console.log("example"));
}

// Or like this, with Function.prototype.bind():
const notTwiceASecond = doTask.bind(null, () => console.log("not twice"));
for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  notTwiceASecond();
}
```

To add its independence of other such schedulers, I make use of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures); specifically, I use a closure for each scheduler to have its own for `queue`, `timeoutId` and `milli`.

Also, to have it alias a function with the same name as your `notTwiceASecond()` function, I make use of [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and am assigning it to a similarly named variable.

#### Improve it!

Obviously my code is not final. Further, it isn't even the only way to do it, and most likely not the best!

For example, the delay is fixed upon "scheduler creation"! You can't first wait for 1s, then for 3s, then for 2s, ...
Maybe this is something you want, or just an exercise idea for you!

Also: Did you notice that my code also has the bug mentioned in "With `async`/`await`"? The one where calling from within the task would make the code misbehave.
Try fixing it as an exercise!

### Regarding your code

Unlike my implementation that uses an array to enqueue each individual "task", you simply increment a counter. Since your `notTwiceASecond()` is always only doing the *same* task, I prefer yours over mine.

What bugs me most about your code is that `available` and `requested` are declared on the global context. Trying to redeclare similarly named variables, or using them differently from their intended use would cause your code to misbehave.

There are different ways to remove them from the global context. These are the ways I can think of right now:

- Using properties on the function. (**Can be hoisted** f [lazy-initialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) and as [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).)
- Wrapping the function in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). (**Not hoisted** because it is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).)

```js
// As properties on the function. (Is hoisted)
function notTwiceASecond() {
  if (!notTwiceASecond.lazyInitialized) {
    notTwiceASecond.available = true;
    notTwiceASecond.requested = 0;
    notTwiceASecond.lazyInitialized = true;
  }

  // Replace `available` and `requested` to property accessors like above.
  // ... (Initial implementation)
}

// Wrapped in IIFE. (Is not hoisted)
const notTwiceASecond = (function() {
  let available = true;
  let requested = 0;
  function notTwiceASecond() { /* ... */ }
  return notTwiceASecond;
})();
```

You inlined the `setTimeout()` call while I outsourced it to its own function `pauseThenContinue()`. The only reason I did this is to have my code be easier to read.

The biggest difference then in our implementations is how we handle `requested`/`queue`:
You immediately execute the call if available and only enqueue if unavailable; I always enqueue and only execute if enqueued. What to prefer here is subjective.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation ! I learned interesting things and will definitely remember this if I need to have multiple functions to queue. Although I think I'll stick with what I've made for the moment because it seems more adapted for a simple function that I don't really need to "queue" but just keep tracks of each call to honor them.

Comment: @Lambdaki I have edited my answer, you may want to re-read it

Comment: I just connected to stack overflow today after monthes and saw this comment... So I know I'm a bit late ^^ Anyway I wanted to thank you again for the time you took to write this really detailed answer. I have read your edit and I actually didn't know that functions were objects that could have properties. I'm glad I leant that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a button or HTML element to trigger your function, you can simply do this:

```js
const anotherFunction = () => {
    console.log('hi');
}
const attemptFunction = () => {
    anotherFunction()
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
    }, 1e3)
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="attemptFunction()">text</button>
```

If you're calling this function using JavaScript or something else (the button is demonstrative):

```js
var available = true;
const anotherFunction = () => {
    console.log('hi');
}
const attemptFunction = () => {
    if(available == true) {
    anotherFunction();
    available = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
        available = true;
    }, 1e3)
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="attemptFunction()">text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
const delay = 1000;
let executedAt = 0;

function fancyFunction(){
    if ((executedAt + delay) < Date.now()){
         // this is where you can execute your code
         console.log('Executing...');
       executedAt = Date.now();
    }
}

// just a test where you will notice the function above 
// only executes once a second.
setInterval(function(){
  fancyFunction();
},200);
```

Comment: This isn't what is expected because previous calls are not queued: for example if the function is called twice in 200 milliseconds it should execute once, then another time after a second and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you asked for, but a lot simpler. Recall the function will cancel it previous call and put a new one in line:

```
let timeOutId;

function notTwiceASecond()  {
     clearTimeout(timeOutId);
     timeOutId = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('test');
    },1000); 
 }
```

You can test on jsbin.com if you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick='notTwiceASecond()'> Test </button>
</body>

<script> 

    let timeOutId;
    
    function notTwiceASecond()  {
        clearTimeout(timeOutId);
        timeOutId = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('teste');
        },1000); 
    }
    
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your solution is a simple debounce, but it was asked to have it still honor _all_ calls, e.g. the function is called 5 times in a row, so it should be called 5 times, but with delays inbetween each call.